# How can I pass a query parameter to a parent component with React-Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So in my Forum.tsx file, I have a link directing to the corresponding id of the post:

```
        <Link to={`/forum/${value.PostId}`}>
          <b>{value.Title}</b>
        </Link>
```

In my app component I want to pass the query parameter somehow and render the ViewPost component:

```
  <Route path={`forum/:postId`} element={<ViewPost />} />
```

But this is obviously not the right way to do it. I would pass the PostId as a prop to the app component, but I know you can't pass props onto parent components in React. Is there another way or a simpler way to get this done?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem you are having is. Can you not use `react-router`'s `useParams` to get the `postId` in your `<ViewPost>` component?

Comment: I've tried throwing in a const { postId } = useParams(); to ViewPost.tsx, but that didn't seem to work so I started to think my whole approach was wrong.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? If so, you need to define the type of your params i.e. `type ViewPostPageParams = { postId: string; }` and strongly type your useParams: `const { postId } = useParams<ViewPostPageParams>();`

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, apparently I forgot the / in

```
<Route path={`forum/:postId`} element={<ViewPost />} />
```

It should be

```
 <Route path={`/forum/:postId`} element={<ViewPost />} />
```